A YT channel manager doesn't see its channel in the consent screen
When I click on "change account" in YT, I see I'm the manager of a specific channel which I cannot see on the consent screen.
How can I fix this?
"change account":

I'm the manager of a specific channel:

But I cannot see it on the consent screen:

